# How to use Laravel routing in existing public directory?

Tags: routes, laravel-5

I have an existing public directory with multiple PHP files and directories, all of which are used for an existing application. I want to drop in Laravel so I can start converting the app over to Laravel. I have added the `.htaccess` and the `index.php` file to the existing public directory. All the existing stuff works fine. However, when I try to access a directory that doesn't exist, the router should catch it an route to the setting I define. However, the routes file is not even being accessed. Any ideas? Does the public directory need to be completely empty?

Comment: Can you post the .htaccess content too? And your Laravel version? I have several applications running under Laravel ( both 4 and 5 ) and my public/ folder is rarely empty and they work fine.

Comment: @CDF thanks for the reply. I found that I was missing the AllowOverride All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! It turns out the .htaccess file was not being used because of my settings in appache. I needed to change

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

I found the solution at [epigroove](http://www.epigroove.com/blog/laravel-routes-not-working-make-sure-htaccess-is-working)

Comment: It would have been pretty hard to figure it out but I immediately aimed at an .htaccess issue ;) Nice one Chuck